# Paginating through foreign key relationships in a web service

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pagination

Suppose I have some relational data:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(200),
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  company_id INTEGER REFERENCES company (id),
  first_name VARCHAR(200),
  last_name VARCHAR(200)
);
```

I want to implement a web service that exposes this data from my database. In this service, I want to be able to return a list of parent objects annotated with lists of child objects. In the request, the user will be able to specify conditions on both parent and child objects.

I want to be able to control the object pagination (I'm planning to use cursors for data integrity). A response would contain, say, up to 100 parent objects, and each parent object would be annotated with up to 100 child objects, and there would be another endpoint to request more records.

So, a request might be something like "get me all companies with name like 'A%', annotated with employees with first_name like 'J%'.

A corresponding response would be:

```
{ 'company': {
    'result': [
      { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Acme',
        'employee': {
           'result': [ {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Joe', 'last_name': 'Blow'},
                       {'id': 2, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Dow'},
                        ... ],
           'cursor': 'adfsfefwwaedvvdwefae'
      },
      ... ],
    'cursor': 'asfddsfwawewwefaewsd'
  }
}
```

The obvious implementation would be to execute the query on the parent object, then execute 100 queries on the child objects, and return 101 opened cursors. My question is, is there some clever trick to implement this more efficiently?

Comment: are you using Oracle REST Data Service?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I'm not familiar with ORDS. Does it have some means to let me paginate through parent and child objects efficiently?

Comment: pagination is built in, and i think the answer to your parent and child is also 'yes'

Comment: I'm not finding any documentation that talks about how this is supported by ORDS. I'd appreciate any pointers

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html

Comment: @thatjeffsmith If I understood the linked documentation correctly, it does not use cursors, and I don't see it providing pagination on child objects. Am I overlooking something?